# Is there a way to use pyqtgraph with pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I'm working on an old code for work, and I "have to" use pyqt4. I will need to check in with whoever initially wrote the code if i really need to stick with pyqt4.

In the meantime, I cant really make the code to run because it also requires pyqtgraph. I guess pyqtgraph used to work with pyqt4, but it's not anymore with the current version of pyqtgraph.

Is there a way to download older version of pyqtgraph that used to work with pyqt4, or is there a work around?

I'm running python3.7 on pycharm on windows, and I installed pyqt4 through Chris Golke's wheel package. i installed pyqtgraph using pip.

Comment: pyqtgraph should still work with PyQt4. Are you trying to import pyqtgraph *before* PyQt? Because it automatically defaults to the most recent version *unless* a previous one has been already imported.

Comment: nope. the first line is importing qtgui and qtcore from pyqt4. then the next is importing pyqtgraph. When I run the code, I get a message that pyqtgraph requires pyqt5, pyqt6, pyside2 and pyside 6.

Comment: nvm. I finally found a page where I can get older pyqtgraph.

Comment: you're right, sorry. It seems that the latest version to support PyQt4 was 0.11.0. See the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/CHANGELOG). If you found a solution, I suggest you to provide your own explanation using the related answer field.